# How to get the model name of a corresponding db table

Tags: django, django-models

I know the table name in mysql that i am working on. I need to find the corresponding model name. Is there a way to find the model name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no API for this but you can get all models and loop through to find the matching db_table:

```
from django.apps import apps

models = apps.get_models()
target = [m for m in models if m._meta.db_table == "my_table_name"]
```

Note, this returns the actual model class, not just the name.